# C++Builder XE5 debugger shows ??? for watches and function's parameters in the Call Stack

Tags: windows, debugging, ide, c++builder, c++builder-xe5

I'm having a lot of trouble working with the C++Builder debugger. I'm using the latest version, XE5, with all patches and updates.

The symptoms are more or less the following: I can run my app and debug it fine once, but if I close the app (either "correctly", or resetting the program in the debugger), the next time I run it it would usually just show ???? for the watches values, and the call stack will show the call stack, but the parameter's functions will usually show also ???.

Closing the IDE and opening again is the only way I've seen to "solve" this. I have tried rebuilding the whole project group, or similar stuff, but that doesn't help.

I'm running on a Windows 7 Pro, 64bits VM, with 6 Gb RAM, 3 processors assigned, plenty of free HD. No strange stuff running on the background: no antivirus, nothing at all except the IDE, Notepad++ and SourceTree. Closing everything except the IDE doesn't help either.

The app is a VCL 32bit app, the project group consists of about 12 packages and 2 exes. I use runtime packages and dynamic rtl. The projects are all new, I mean, the were not updated from projects of previous versions of C++Builder: all of them were done from the beginnning here.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the IDE/debugger.  You should post a bug report to [Quality Central](http://qc.embarcadero.com) if one does not already exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, if you disable the "Load All Symbols" in the Debugger section of the Project Options, and just add there the modules you do want to be able to debug into, the problems are somewhat mitigated.

Doing so has made my Debugger session behave correctly, showing the values for the inspectors and not hanging.

[Update, July 2016] The newest version, 10.1 Berlin, appears to have fixed this most of the time. I haven't had this problem occur to me except for maybe 1 time in a couple of months now.